# Le mot "divisibilité" (nombre de "i")

Tags: vocabulaire

Avec mon fils nous cherchons des mots avec le plus grand nombre de voyelles identiques. Est-ce qu'il y a un mot du français qui a plus de "i" que le mot divisibilité ?

Comment: [exionnaire](https://www.forum.exionnaire.com/dico-3524-record-d-occurrences-d-une-meme-lettre-dans-un-mot#7-fois-la-meme-lettre-zom) donne (bon à faire connaitre) deux mots avec 6 « i » : inintélligibilité indivisibilité

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Désolé de vous souffler la trouvaille, mais il y a « indivisibilité »  ! Je crois qu'il va être difficile d'en trouver un qui comprenne 7 i…

Answer (score 4):

En voilà un qui contient quinze **I** :

> [image]

Candice Kornberg-Anzel, Camille Skrzynski, Olivier Barbin, *Le guide décapant des parents imparfaits - L'école maternelle*, 2017

D'autres avec treize et vingt-trois **E** :

> [image] [image]

Matt Haig, *La fille qui a sauvé Noël*, 2017
et
Pascal Carretier, *Le cycle de Sarah Webster - 1*, 2011

Et enfin, cinquante **U** là :

> [image]

Tom Oldfield, Félix Huet, Matt Oldfield, *Ronaldo: Les Superstars du foot*, 2019

;-)

Comment: Et qu'aurait-ce  été si on avait remonté les générations jusqu'au Moyen-Âge !

Comment: Dans l'esprit, il y aurait aussi pour U le *buuuuuuuuuut* avec 10 U* ... :-) http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=175.0

Comment: @aCOSwt Merci pour l'idée !